# IIS Showing Application Request Routing Cache But Not Application Request Routing

Tags: iis, iis-10

I'm attempting to set up some reverse proxy rules using Application Request Routing. However, when I open IIS, I can only see an option for "Application Request Routing Cache" not the actual "Application Request Routing".

[image: IIS]

I've tried re-installing ARR through the Web Platform Installer, but no change.

One note is that this is a Windows 10 Pro box, not a Windows Server instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After installing ARR, you can create the reverse proxy rules with "URL Rewrite" (I can see that this module is installed, based on your screenshot).

> ARR relies on the URL rewrite module to inspect incoming HTTP requests to make the routing decisions.

[Using the Application Request Routing Module](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/planning-for-arr/using-the-application-request-routing-module)